# PHP Phalcon, как добавить правильно данные к пользователю?

Tags: php, phalcon

Пытаюсь добавить данные от пользователя, который зашёл к себе на страницу:

    `public function useraddaboutAction()
        {`

```
        if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            $user = new Users();

            $success = $user->save(
                $this->request->getPost(),
                [
                    "about"
                ]

            );


            if ($success) {
                $this->flashSession->success("Вы добавили информацию о 
                                                себе");
                return $this->response-
                       >redirect("/users/usershow/$user->name");

            } else {
                echo "Произошли следующие проблемы: <br>";

                $messages = $user->getMessages();

                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    echo $message->getMessage(), "<br/>";
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

При добавлении выдают ошибки, то есть требует поля имя пользователя и емайл. Как добавить данные к пользователю ? И еще вопрос. Как передать параметр name в адресную строку через ссылку в представлении ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$success = $user->save(
    $this->request->getPost(),
    [
        "about"
    ]
);
```

Вы сами говорите модели, что она может доверять только полю `about`, это означает что все остальное в `POST` будет игнорироваться, вы или добавьте все нужные поля в данный массив, или устанавливайте значения явно.

```
$user->name = ...;
$user->email = ...;
$user->about = ...;
$user->save();
```

Не точно, но помнится мне что хотели убрать массовое присвоение, не утверждаю, не эксперт в Phalcon

[Источник](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#creating-updating-records)

Comment: Так зачем мне добавлять другие поля, если я хочу добавить данные в одно поле about ?

Comment: Вы создаете новую модель Users, у нее есть правила волидации, в них указано что при изминениях (создание/обновление) должны быть поля почта и имя, вы их ему не даете, он ругается, что вас не устраивает? Вы или не правильно строите вопрос, или сами не понимаете чего хотите)

Comment: Да уже разобрался, спасибо за ответы!